# How to calculate the output voltage of the mirror circuit?

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, current-mirror

Please refer the following circuit added.

[image]

Output voltage (Vout-A) is measured as follows,
[image]

Following is the way I have started analysis:
Krichhoff's voltage law around the loop ( R12 -> R3 -> V_BE(Q2) -> V_BE(Q1) ) can be used to calculated the voltage across R12
This drop across R12 will be equal to drop across R3 (10 Ω)

But when measures in Ltspice, Voltage across R3 = 12.56 mV
Voltage across R12 = 23.7 mV
As per my understanding voltage - drop across the R12 and R3 will be equal, and it should be 12.56 mV.
Why voltage across R12 is 23.7 mV? 
I suspect that D1 and R5 plays a role.

My intention is to calculate the output voltage Vout-A.
Could anyone suggest a method to find the output voltage Vout-A?

**Edit**
" it should be 12.56 V " changed to " it should be 12.56 mV".

Comment: *voltage - drop across the R12 and R3 will be equal, and it should be 12.56 V* Whoa!! Time for a sanity check: R3 is 10 ohms, 12.56 V / 10 ohms = 1.256 A Are you sure so much current should be flowing? Maybe you mean mV then it is 1.256 mA, makes more sense. But R12 has a 50x higher value than R3 so the current will also differ by a factor 50. That seems like a lot to me. My suggestion: forget about applying K's laws for a moment and **think** how the circuit should work and what currents should flow. You're now already analyzing the ouput while (I think) the circuit isn't working correctly.

Comment: There is one more resistor R6, that is 10 kΩ. This will come in to picture and effective current through the R3 will be around 1.2 mA. Please check

Comment: That R6 of 10 k does basically "nothing". Proof: R3 and R6 form a voltage divider for the 12 V supply. The output voltage (across R6) will be 12V * (10k/10.01k) = 11.988V and the impedance to ground at that point will be 10ohm//10kohm = 9.99 ohms. Conclusion: R6 changes things about 0.1% so little that it doesn't do anything significant to the circuit's operation. You're still not **thinking** how this circuit (should) work. Yes, that's difficult. But if you want to get further, there is no way around it. Just applying all laws and formulas will not get you there.

Comment: Does the 100K startup resistor ever go away?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, No. It is fixed

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie,  
FYI, Yes, High current is possible and it is the requirement. Load current (Current through R3) maximum will be around 12 A. 
Ideally R6 is used to control the load current or current through R3. 
And circuit need to produce a voltage at output (Vout-A) againest to the load current passing through R3.
I dont know what is the issue with 50 factor of current.

Comment: *Yes, High current is possible* No it's not, the current cannot go anywhere, at least, you didn't indicate where it goes. Is the current supposed to come out of Vout-A? Not possible as a BC817 cannot support more than 0.5A. The deal with the factor 50 higher current is that you claim that R12 and R3 must have the same voltage drop. That means I(R3) = 50 * I(R12) (because R12 has a 50x higher value). With the circuit as you show it: **that current ratio is not possible**.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. The output means resistor R6. This is where power is consumed.
Consider the case of system working at around 1A, so equivalent to that I will make R6 in miliohm range to get the load current in 1 A range.

Vout-A is the output of the current mirror circuit. That will be in milivolt range. My intention is to calculate the Vout-A (current mirror output) against to the load current. Hope this clarifies it

Comment: You have assumed that the Vbe voltage of both transistors is identical. Why don't you take a look at the simulation and see if that is true?

Comment: That is one possibility. Ideally when do the analysis in paper, V_be is assumes as equal. So for paper calculation it will be tough to accommodate the V_be change. Can anyone comment the effect of D1 ?